Identity?: $\frac{\varphi(2^n-1)}{n}=\frac{2^{\varphi(2^n-1)}-1 \bmod (2^n-1)^2}{2^n-1}$
The computer found this.
Let $n$ be a positive integer.
Up to $n=200$ we have:
$$\frac{\varphi(2^n-1)}{n}=\frac{2^{\varphi(2^n-1)}-1 \bmod (2^n-1)^2}{2^n-1}. \tag{1}\label{483144_1}$$

Q1 Is \eqref{483144_1} true?

Observe that the LHS is exponential in $n$ and the RHS is doubly exponential
in $n$ and we reduce modulo $(2^n-1)^2$.
Sage code:
def mers1(n):  return euler_phi(2**n-1)/n
def mers2(n):
   return lift((Integers((2**n-1)**2)(2))**euler_phi(2**n-1)-1)/(2**n-1)


Note that for $n=1$, $\varphi(1)/1=1$, while $(1 \bmod 1)/1=0$. So I guess $n>1$.

Denote by $a$ the left hand side and $m = 2^n - 1$. We know that $a$ is an integer, since $n$ is the order of $2$ in $(\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z})^*$.
We want to prove that $2^{an} - 1 - am \equiv 0 \pmod{m^2}$. But $2^n = m + 1$ and hence it is equivalent to $(m + 1)^a - 1 - am \equiv 0 \pmod{m^2}$ which is clear.

Thanks, this is of interest. I edited clarifying that I am working over the integers and congruence is not a full answer to the question.

But $\varphi(2^n-1)/n<2^n-1$, so this is complete. It is a prime example of why formulating things as in (1) is harder to work with than congruences and inequalities.

@ChrisWuthrich I still fail to understand why congruence $\mod{m^2}$ in which there is exponent $a=(\varphi(2^n-1))/n$ implies equality over the integers.

@joro You want the identity $am = (2^{an}-1 \pmod{m^2})$. I assume that by equality over integers you mean that the right hand side is a number less than $m^2$. But $am < m^2$, that is why congruence $\mod m^2$ is enough.

@joro Remember that Euler's totient fulfils $0<\varphi(m)<m$ for $m=2^n-1>1$. Your identity holds for arbitrary functions $\phi(m)=a n$ with this property.

Thanks, I think you are right.

@FredHucht Thanks, I also noticed, that the main result of the answer works for random $a$ too.

I asked related identities for (2^n+1)/3: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/483951/wieferich-primes-and-identities-for-the-euler-quotients-of-2n1-and-frac2
